# Splitting Date Range by Month and Category

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table with the following columns: Reportdate, Category.

```
Reportdate     Category
-------------------
01/01/2013     IT
01/01/2013     Grounds
01/01/2013     HVAC
01/03/2013     HVAC
02/01/2013     IT
02/02/2013     IT
02/02/2013     HVAC
02/02/2013     Grounds
```

I need a query that will output the following:

```
           Jan     Feb
---------------------------    
IT         1       2
Grounds    1       1
HVAC       2       1
```

If someone can help I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need a [`PIVOT`](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is with conditional aggregation:

```
select category,
       sum(case when extract(month from reportdate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
       sum(case when extract(month from reportdate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb
from table
group by category;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `PIVOT` or you might try the following:

```
SELECT category
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 1, 1, 0)) AS "Jan"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 2, 1, 0)) AS "Feb"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 3, 1, 0)) AS "Mar"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 4, 1, 0)) AS "Apr"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 5, 1, 0)) AS "May"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 6, 1, 0)) AS "Jun"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 7, 1, 0)) AS "Jul"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 8, 1, 0)) AS "Aug"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 9, 1, 0)) AS "Sep"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 10, 1, 0)) AS "Oct"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 11, 1, 0)) AS "Nov"
     , SUM(DECODE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM reportdate), 12, 1, 0)) AS "Dec"
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY category
```

If you want to differentiate by year that could complicate things!